# Larmour frequency in elecron scopic resonance spectrometer

Tags: magnetic-fields, atomic-physics

the formulla of larnour frequency is $w=(e/2m)B$, Here w is angular frequncy
but in the experimental manual of ESR is w=(e/2mc)**H**,here h magnetic field intentsity
the question is how the formulla is convert.
If anyone know pls tell me the proof or any link related to this.

Comment: Older books use letter $\mathbf H$ in the CGS system of units instead of $\mathbf B$ in SI system of units to refer to magnetic field

Comment: But sir how the factor of 1/c added in this formula, this formula is written in many manual. here c is velocity of light

Comment: Because of using CGS, magnetic field $H$ has the same unit as electric field $E$ and magnetic field $B$, so magnetic force on charged particle in vacuum is $q\mathbf v/c\times \mathbf H$.